# Using ethernet ports on Surfboard SBG6580 in bridge mode

Tags: router, home-networking, ethernet, bridge, airport-extreme

**tl;dr:** I have a Surfboard SBG6580 modem/router combo running in bridge mode with an Airport Extreme as the main router. I want to be able to use the Ethernet ports on the Surfboard to attach additional non-wireless devices to the network.

I'm visiting my parents for the holidays and trying to get all of the miscellaneous gadgets they've got to join their network in a way that isn't ugly. (They've just moved, so this isn't the network I carefully set up for them in the first place.)

They have a Motorola Surfboard SBG6580 modem/router combo and a 5th gen Airport Extreme. I have successfully gotten the Surfboard to run in bridge mode, so the Airport Extreme is serving as the actual router and creating the wireless network.

The trouble is that they have a whole lot of devices (7?) that need a wired network connection: more devices than there are ethernet ports on the Airport Extreme. I'm hoping I can run them from Surfboard's ethernet ports, but so far I'm not having any luck. I've tried just plugging them in and hoping for the best, but they return a message that they cannot connect to the internet. I can't locate any settings on the Surfboard that seem relevant — most of the options disappeared when I disabled NAPT — and the Airport Extreme doesn't have a nice way of seeing its wired clients (possibly my biggest complaint about it), so I'm not sure if there's anything it can do to help.

Does anyone know if there's a way to do this? If not I'll probably just find a cheap Ethernet switch, but I hate adding another box to the chain if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this. if you're using the modem as a bridge, then it can only be on one side of the router. It clearly must be on the WAN side because it has the connection to the WAN. Thus it cannot be on the LAN side.

You need a switch.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was suspecting, but I'd seen some mention of the "router" portion of the Surfboard being separate from the "modem" portion, so I hoped there might be some way around it. The documentation for the Surfboard leaves much to be desired.